# When loading a web page in UIWebView in iphone, the click does not work

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, click, hyperlink

I use and UIWebView in my application to load www.google.com. After the page is loaded, I am not able to click on any of the links. Basically the links dont work. Am I missing something ?

Comment: As always, please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are user interactions for your UIWebView by any chance not enabled?  If you used InterfaceBuilder to create the view check to see if the **User Interactions Enabled** property for you UIWebView is checked.  Programmatically, you can check the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the web view is set to `YES`.  Also check that interactions are enabled for any parent views that contain your web view.

Answer (score 0):

In UI builder is a checkbox that allows to capture links phone numbers and you have to tick those to enable links ...